# Finding index of a pandas DataFrame value

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to process some .csv data using pandas, and I am struggling with something that I am sure is a rookie move, but after spending a lot of time trying to make this work, I need your help.

Essentially, I am trying to find the index of a value within a dataframe I have created.

```
max = cd_gross_revenue.max()
#max value of the cd_gross_revenue dataframe

print max
#finds max value, no problem!

maxindex = cd_gross_revenue.idxmax()
print maxindex
#finds index of max_value, what I wanted!

print max.index
#ERROR: AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'index'
```

The maxindex variable gets me the answer using idxmax(), but what if I am not looking for the index of a max value? What if it is some random value's index that I am looking at, how would I go about it? Clearly .index does not work for me here.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Does this dataframe have only 1 column or do you know which column has the max value? if you know the column then `df.loc[df.col == max].index` would return you the index

Comment: Hi EdChum, thanks for your answer. Doing this gives me the following error
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "psims2.py", line 81, in <module>
    print cd_gross_revenue.loc[cd_gross_revenue.col == max].index
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.14.1-py2.7-win32.egg\pandas\core\generic.py", line 18
43, in __getattr__
    (type(self).__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'col'`

Comment: I think you misunderstand, `col` was a generic name for your column of interest so substitute the column name with the one from your df, my question is how many columns does this df have and is there only 1 or do you know which column has the max value, if so the subsitute `col` with that name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `boolean mask` to get the rows where the value is equal to the random variable.
Then use that mask to index the dataframe or series.
Then you would use the `.index` field of the pandas dataframe or series. An example is:

```
In [9]: s = pd.Series(range(10,20))

In [10]: s
Out[10]:

0    10
1    11
2    12
3    13
4    14
5    15
6    16
7    17
8    18
9    19
dtype: int64

In [11]: val_mask = s == 13

In [12]: val_mask

Out[12]:
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
dtype: bool

In [15]: s[val_mask]
Out[15]:
3    13
dtype: int64

In [16]: s[val_mask].index
Out[16]: Int64Index([3], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 4):

`s[s==13]`

Eg,

```
from pandas import Series

s = Series(range(10,20))
s[s==13]

3    13
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

When you called idxmax it returned the key in the index which corresponded to the max value. You need to pass that key to the dataframe to get that value.

```
max_key = cd_gross_revenue.idxmax()
max_value = cd_gross_revenue.loc[max_key]
```